# Google Chrome Request - Negative connecting time

Tags: http, google-chrome, connection, request, httprequest

How come a connecting time in an http request made by Google Chrome, can be negative?

[image: Negative connecting time]

Best Regards

Comment: Could it be that the connection is shared by several requests and was already open when the given request started?

Comment: Already thought of that possibility. But in that case shouldn't be 0?

Comment: After further investigation this looks like a bug, because if a connection is already open upon request initialization Chrome does normally not show Connecting timing at all.

Comment: There is a related bug filed in the [Chromium project](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152201).